# My ps3 loading times just going thru a door is excruciatingly long. why?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I have been playing Skyrim on my PS3, but of recent going through load doors takes a very long time. Does anyone know a way to reduce the load time?

Comment: You need to do better than just fill the body with random noise.  Please edit your question to give us more details, such as if it's a specific door only, how long you've been playing, whether it happens at other points, that sort of thing.

Comment: Skyrim has to load massive amounts of data per room, so, the longer you play, expect longer loading.

Comment: @Dingo I edited the question to make it into a real question. If you have any more details, please edit them in yourself.

Answer (score 3):

The bigger the save file, the longer the loading times. Skyrim does an autosave every time you leave or enter an area, and the more it has to save, the longer it takes. Even on PC, loading times can be insanely long. The only way to fix this on PC is using an SSD which will speed up loadingtimes significantly (or maybe even a ramdisk which will annihilate any loadingtimes).

This is a problem all versions of skyrim have, no only PS3. There is no way to fix this, except you want to upgrade your PS3 with an SSD.